Differentiating $x|x|$ with first definition of derivative
In my textbook, I saw a question regarding the first definition of the derivative.
Find $f'(x)$ of $f(x) = x|x|$
Here's my working:
$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{(x+h)|x+h| - x|x|}{h} $$
$$ = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{(x+h)\sqrt{(x+h)^2} - x\sqrt{(x)^2}}{h} $$
$$ = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{(x+h)^4} - \sqrt{(x)^4}}{h}$$
$$ = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac {(x+h)^2 - (x)^2}{h}$$
$$ = 2x$$
However, the textbook says it's $2|x|$. I suspect my error is in the line where I moved in the $(x+h)$ and $x$, then canceled it, but I do not understand why this operation is invalid. An alternative solution I saw multiplied the top and bottom by $(x+h)\sqrt{(x+h)^2} + x\sqrt{x^2}$, and managed to avoid this issue.
Why does what I do not work, and why does multiplying the top and bottom in that fashion preserve the absolute values?

$x |x| \neq \sqrt{x^4}$. It should be $x |x| = (\operatorname{sgn} x) \sqrt{x^4}$.

$x\sqrt {x^2} \ne \sqrt{x^4}$

$x\sqrt{x^2}=\sqrt{x^4}$ only when $x\ge0$

I would investigate this when $x>0$, $x<0$, and $x=0$ separately so you can replace absolute value bars with something simpler in the first two cases.

The problem occurs when you say that $x \sqrt{x^2} = \sqrt{x^4}$. Instead it is the sign of $x$ times $\sqrt{x^4}$. An easier way to solve the problem is to consider positive and negative values of $x$ separately, although this way is technically doable.

To evaluate it separately, would I find two expressions for $f'(x)$ for $x<0$ and $x\geq 0$?

@AudricJardine Yes, you're are correct

Second line to third line you made the mistake. Here is the thing:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x^2 &  x\geq 0\\
-x^2&  x<0
\end{cases}$$
We first calculate $f'(0)$
$$
\lim_{h\to 0+}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0+}\frac{h^2}{h}=0.
$$
$$
\lim_{h\to 0-}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0-}\frac{-h^2}{h}=0.
$$
Thus, $f'(0)=0$. Now, we calculate $f'(x)$ whenever $x>0$.
$$
\lim_{h\to 0+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0+}\frac{(x+h)^2-x^2}{h}=2x\quad (\text{by using L'Hospital}).
$$
$$
\lim_{h\to 0-}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0-}\frac{(x+h)^2-x^2}{h}=2x\quad (\text{by using L'Hospital}).
$$
Thus, $f'(x)=2x$ whenever $x>0$. Finally, we calculate $f'(x)$ whenever $x<0$.
$$
\lim_{h\to 0+}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0+}\frac{-(x+h)^2+x^2}{h}=-2x\quad (\text{by using L'Hospital}).
$$
$$
\lim_{h\to 0-}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0-}\frac{-(x+h)^2+x^2}{h}=-2x\quad (\text{by using L'Hospital}).
$$
Therefore,
$$
f'(x)=\begin{cases}
2x &  x> 0\\
0 &  x= 0\\
-2x &  x< 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Consequently, $f'(x)=2|x|$.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. +1 for the only answer that's really careful at $0$. Even if the question allowed us to use more than the definition of derivatives, e.g. the product rule, such care would still be needed because $|x|$ isn't differentiable there.(You needn't split $x=0$ into two one-sided limits though.)

There's no need to use L'Hopital's rule

Simpler approach is

For $~x \geq 0~: f(x) = x^2  \implies f'(x) = 2x.$

For $~x < 0~: f(x) = -x^2 \implies f'(x) = -2x.$


The idea is to remove the absolute value sign from the $~f(x)~$ specification, and only then differentiate.
